# Un mot pour dire "mettre un cadavre à la mer"

Tags: vocabulaire

Lorsque l'on met un cercueil en terre on parle d'enterrement ou d'inhumation, et lorsque le défunt est brûlé on parle de crémation.

Existe-t-il un mot équivalent pour désigner l'acte de mettre un cadavre à la mer ? Je pense par exemple au cas d'Oussama Ben Laden ou bien aux obsèques en mer organisée par des sociétés privées américaines ([lien](http://www.courrierinternational.com/article/2011/05/19/que-devient-un-cadavre-jete-a-la-mer)).

Par ailleurs, il semble que cette pratique ne soit pas très répandue en France. Même des grands navigateurs comme Tabarly ou Artaud ont été enterrés lors de leurs funérailles. Existe-t-il des cas récent de telles obsèques en mer ?

Comment: *Emmerrer* serait une invention... (si tu inclus les néologismes dans le specte de ta question ?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comme le détaille le TLFi, le mot simple est clairement "**immersion**" :
A 2. […] − En partic. [Correspond à immerger A 2; spécialement à propos d'un marin mort en mer] Action d'ensevelir dans la mer : 
*... à mon commandement, la planche bascula et on entendit le bruit sourd d'un grand remous dans les eaux (...). Le soir de l'immersion de Barazère, Yves avait amené son ami Jean Barrada dans ma chambre avec lui.* Loti, Mon frère Yves,1883, p. 371.

Eu égard à la rareté de cette pratique, il peut s'avérer utile de le compléter : obsèques, funérailles par immersion.

Answer (score 7):

Cette pratique n'est pas seulement peu répandue elle est apparemment interdite :

> ... il n'est donc pas possible en France de choisir l'immersion comme mode
>   de sépulture, seule l'immersion des **cendres** peut être autorisée.

Source : [JuriTravail](http://www.juritravail.com/Actualite/deces-sepulture/Id/4116)

Seules les cendres peuvent être immergées donc.

Sinon pour revenir au nom de ce procédé on trouve "**sépulture en mer**" :

> La sépulture en mer est l'opération consistant à immerger un cadavre
>   dans la mer ou l'océan, ou à y disperser ses cendres

Source : [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9pulture_en_mer)

Answer (score 5):

On trouve « [**enseveli en mer**](http://correcteurs.blog.lemonde.fr/2011/05/02/leche-typographique-a-lelysee-du-choix-des-mots/) », « **immergé** », « **sépulture par immersion** » ou « [**sépulture en mer**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9pulture_en_mer) ».

Référence: [Termium plus](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=ENSEVELISSEMENT%20MER).

Comme déjà évoqué, la pratique est interdite en France sauf s'il s'agit de cendres après une crémation. On parlera alors de « **dispersion des cendres en mer** ».

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y pas de mot, pour ce qui est du coté legal on ne peut pas mettre un cadavre à la mer en France, on peut seulement vider l'urne funéraire à plus de 300m de la côte ou alors enterrer une urne funéraire biodégradable à plus de 3 miles(4.8Km) de la mer. Il faut prévenir les autorités pour obtenir une autorisation.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse, mais ça  ne répond pas à la question. Sur quelle base vous appuyez-vous pour dire qu'il n'y a pas de mot? J'imagine que vous ne connaissez pas tous les mots du dictionnaire ... Merci pour les aspects légaux. Mais on sait bien que tout le monde ne respecte pas la loi: connaît-on des cas illégaux?